# Performance difference Firestore through Firebase Functions vs Firestore SDK

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Our team is developing a mobile app and is currently in use of (Firebase) Firestore for our backend. We wrapped every DB access with Firebase Functions in order to clean up the object returned to the client app.

Does this approach introduce any (additional) unignorable overhead compared to accessing to Firestore directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes but No** depending on your use case.

If you have small amount of users with relatively **low usage** (in terms of the given quota), it is recommended to apply Cloud Functions.  As stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas), Firebase Cloud Function offers big quota in terms of Resource limits, Time limits and Rate limits with good pricing especially for the Spark plan (FREE).

[image: Firebase Pricing]

The **advantage** of using Cloud Functions is that it has a **high speed** and **scalable computing / processing unit** which could shorten the processing time of a specific function as compared with using the mobile phone CPU which in some cases the mobile phones has low computing power (have to consider various users as not everyone own a high spec phone), in order to provide better user experience (UX), all this hassle can be done by Cloud Function!

Note: I do agree with Doug where cost is one of the factor, but we should also consider the performance and other perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at the very least, now your path to get data has two hops instead of one.  Before, you directly accessed the database using a channel that's optimized for returning the query results.  Now, you have to pay the cost of an additional hop to Cloud Functions, which makes the query.  And it's possible that the results returned to the client are bigger than if you made the query directly.

Perhaps the biggest loss you'll experience is the client side caching of documents that's automatically performed by the client (enabled by default on Android and iOS).  If you repeat a query and none of the documents have changed, you get immediate results from the cache instead of having to wait for the server.  And you won't have to pay for document reads for cache hits.  So, if you aren't also caching your results, you're also paying the monetary cost of Cloud Functions *and* the query to Firestore for every request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the answer could be different based on the situation.

If a client wants to fetch a record exactly as in the database, the Firebase SDK might be faster because there is no overhead calling the Firebase Functions.

If we have a heavy processing after fetching a record, then Firebase Functions + Firebase Admin SDK could be faster because the processing unit in Firebase Functions could be faster than mobile CPU. However, if the request responds faster, the client app could display an additional message that something was fetched and currently in process during the heavy processing, the user experience could be acceptable.

The only case I can come up with Firebase Functions could always win is that the server reduces the data size so that the overhead introduced by Firebase Functions (including processing time) was compensated by the shorter network delay. This also has advantage of saving client's data plan.